# Send action to child controller (needs doesn't work for child)

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've got three controller `base`, `base.player` and `base.post`.

`base` is listening to some jQuery events on the content of `base.post` and I'd like to send an action/call a function to/of the `base.player` controller from `base`.

I tried `needs: "player"`but I get an error that it can't be found.
If I try `needs: "base.player"` I get an error that dots can't be used in needs.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to send actions downwards, but I wouldn't recommend it. Ember 2.0 is "data down, actions up". I would put a property on your parent controller and then observe it in the child controllers.

Comment: can you elaborate more on what `base.player` is? That's not a standard naming convention.  I agree with @GJK that there's likely a much better way of doing this, you probably want a `component`.

Comment: I could turn my player into a component. Look at http://ali.dj its my html5 player in the header. I want to be able to send SoundCloud songs from blog posts to it. Currently it can only play Songs from within itself.